# Which tags are most/least likely to have an accepted answer selected?

Tags: discussion, tags, accepted-answer, statistics

Any StackDB gurus want to take a stab at this?

I've noticed that in my personal experience of answering questions any kind of homework/puzzle programming puzzle is least likely to generate a "best answer" selection.  Python users live up to their stereotype by almost always selecting one.  Of course this is just my extremely skewed perception... what's your take?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting data point - I'd like to see this, especially with tags ranked in order from most likely to least likely.  I imagine a crosstab of this with a few other variables would be telling as well - perhaps # of answers, time of day/day of week posted, rep of OP, votes...

Answer (score 2):

I've extracted some stats that you can see here: http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/tagstats.html

Click on the column headings to sort by that column. To reduce the data volume, this only contains data for tags with 10 questions or more.

Comment: This is some solid analysis! Congrats!